# Retrieving a CSV file in lib/assets directory in Rails 3.2 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, heroku

I deployed Harry's prelaunchr microsite whose code can be found here https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr on Heroku and it says I have to run this rake task `bundle exec rake prelaunchr:create_winner_csvs` and the app will export the CSVs in the `\lib\assets` folder. I run the task on Heroku but I have no idea how to get the CSVs from heroku. Any idea?

Comment: File structure is pretty much locked down on heroku after deploy. Your going to have to change the code to upload the file to an external source like Amazon S3 or the like when done.

Comment: But the rake task runs successfully.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

Comment: "The following types of behaviors are not supported:...Saving uploaded assets to local disk (e.g. with attachment_fu or paperclip)" Basically is letting the app think its writing out, but then takes the output and puts it in a blackhole.

Comment: How would I make it write to amazon S3 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work on heroku you are going to need to output the file to an external source from the rake task, due to the reasons state above in the comments. You can do this using the fog gem. While I am unsure of your requires the basic idea would be once the file is being done written to use the fog gem to do a direct upload to an S3 bucket and then save the results of this upload to your database, or output them in a way that you will be able to safely access them. The gem can be found here.

https://github.com/fog/fog

Comment: I have a small issue, even if I run the rake task on my local machine. I have no idea how to access the csvs. Help me read through the readme on github. Maybe you can understand better what I need to do.

Comment: You need to create a AWS account, then create an S3 bucket, then you should have web access to said bucket, so after upload it should be int he bucket where you told fog to upload it for you. If you want you can even use the result from fog and save it to your database, or use carrierwave gem to handle the whole upload process for you, which will save the information to the database and give you helpful methods for displaying the url in your app.